# Why println doesn't show my array

Tags: java, arrays, println

```
public static void displayArray(int tab[]){
    int i;
    String choix; // choice


    System.out.println("\n you want to see the values you entred from first position or last ?");
    System.out.println("tape "P" for first , and"D" for last);
    choix=sc1.nextLine(); // sc1 for nextLine , sc for nextInt to avoid buffering problems .

    if(choix=="p"||choix=="P") 
    {    for(i=0;i<k;i++)      //k is the maximum of the array(max index)
        System.out.println("T["+i+"]= "+tab[i]); // why this instruction doesn't work ??

    }

    if(choix=="D"||choix=="d")
    {for(i=k-1;i>=0;i--)
        System.out.println("T["+i+"]= "+tab[i]);// this one too doesn't work

    }}      


     public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method;stub
         int tab[]=new int[4];

         System.out.println(readIntArray(tab));
         displayArray(tab);
    }    
}
```

I don't understand why `displayArray` doesn't work, `System.out.println` should print my array after checking the condition but it doesn't work.

Comment: Your code doesn't work since one of your print is wrong : 
`System.out.println("tape 'P' for first , and 'D' for last");`

Comment: `//k is the maximum of the array(max index)` ... Ok, so where did you set `k`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are comparing `Object`s, `==` not only compares their value, but compares the given objects as well. For example:

```
String a = "foo";
String b = "foo";
a == b; //false
a.equals(b); //true
```

since `equals` compares whether the objects are similar, `==` compares whether the objects are the same. Also, if you are using quotes inside a `String`, you need to escape them with `\"`, since if you use just use `"` then you are closing the `String`, resulting in errors. So, you should do something like this:

```
public static void displayArray(int tab[]){
    int i;
    String choix; // choice


    System.out.println("\n you want to see the values you entred from first position or last ?");
    System.out.println("tape \"P\" for first , and\"D\" for last);
    choix=sc1.nextLine(); // sc1 for nextLine , sc for nextInt to avoid buffering problems .

    if(choix.equals("p")||choix.equals("P")) 
    {    for(i=0;i<k;i++)      //k is the maximum of the array(max index)
        System.out.println("T["+i+"]= "+tab[i]); // why this instruction doesn't work ?? 
        //Your code did not even reach this point due to using unescape quotes inside a String and incorrect comparisons in your if

    }

    if(choix.equals("D")||choix.equals("d"))
    {for(i=k-1;i>=0;i--)
        System.out.println("T["+i+"]= "+tab[i]);// this one too doesn't work
        //The reason is the very same as above

    }}      


     public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method;stub
         int tab[]=new int[4];

         System.out.println(readIntArray(tab));
         displayArray(tab);
    }    
}
```

Also, you need to structure your code, since, as it is, it is difficult to read it.

Comment: Thank for explanation , sorry i did mistake while copying my program , i typed " " instead of ' ' in println , program works fine now thank you

Answer (score 0):

I assume it's in Java.
When you compare string use

```
string.equals(String)
```

Instead of *==*

It should work with :

```
if(choix.equals("p") || choix.equals("P"))
if(choix.equals("D") || choix.equals("d"))
```